# how to get the text from an editable <td> from user input?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a game here, and i'm still at the 10% of this game so far. Its called "SOS" familiar? like tic tac toe but not "X"  & "O" BUT "S" and "O" in 5x5, and ill be using javascript. now i have an editable td's

```
<table id="myTable" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width:30%;" cellpadding="8">
                    <!-- 1st row -->
                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- 2nd row -->
                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- 3rd row -->
                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- 4th row -->
                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- 5th row -->
                    <tr>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                        <td contenteditable="true"></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```

if i will input a text inside this td how can i get it to campare with the other td? because to score in this game i have to form the word SOS vertically, Diagonally and horizontally. Please do help:) thanks Javascripters:)

```
example: consider this are td's. the 1st player inputs "S". The second player inputs "0". Then the 1st player again inputs "S". Then that's a score for player 1.

[S][O][S][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use data-x & data-y attributes on each td, something like

```
<td data-x="0" data-y="0"> X/O </td>
<td data-x="0" data-y="1"> X/O </td>
...
...
<td data-x="4" data-y="4"> X/O </td>
```

Now, you can access the value at a given i & j as

```
$('td[data-x="' + i + '"][data-y="' + j + '"]').text()
```

And I don't think there is a need to use `contenteditable=true`

$ - jQuery

If you're not using jQuery or using plain Javascript then let's do the below:

```
<td id="x0y0"> X/O </td>
<td id="x0y1"> X/O </td>
...
...    
<td id="x4y4"> X/O </td>
```

Then you can access the value at i & j as

```
document.getElementById('x'+i+'y'+j).value
```

Comment: wait, the game is expecting a user input which the choices are "S" and "O" so the td should be editable. ill edit my post above

Comment: You can use a Flag : Player 1 & Player 2.
Instead of entering the input just Clicks should add the S or O.

Say Flag: Player1 then when the user click on the TD insert S into that field, and then change the Flag: Player2 now the click will insert O ... and go on until the game is completed.

Comment: ahhh.. , but user237865 can you show me how to get the value of my td and store it in a variable? i just dont know how, i tried google search but havent found anything that could help me.

Comment: please create your code here: http://codepen.io/pen then I can help you fix issues, if any.